# Do you know how to slide content like it was a cinematography reel with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

I´m working in the realization of a web side for a Film producer. The client requests
that the page must work as a cinematography reel. Imagining in this way,

Example image:

[image: http://www.virtualservidores.com/uploads-imagen/?di=1133234847816]

When I enter in the “future” web side, I´m the red point and the cinematography reel is 
around me, so the images and information when I click them, should pass to the right side 
and the previous information should be in the left side. I mean when a choose an element 
from  the top menu, the main container that has images and information must enter from the
 right and the previous images and information must  come out from the left.

Now the question is. Do you know some plugin to do this?

---

EDIT: No It´s not what I need, I know what a carousel or a images slider is, but what I need is a non flat carousel, I want a carousel that act as cylinder. I would like to see the flat shaped container (A rectangle on the screen), and when It moves out of the screen I want to see it arched like following the trayectory of a cylinder (seen it from its center) and that the new information enters fron the other side of the screen in the same way but in the other direction! Do you know any way to do this?

---

UPDATE

This is a video of the effect that I need: - deleted video (if anyone needs to watch it, send me an email)

Comment: It's called a carousel, and there's plenty of implementations. I would start [here](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/).

Comment: probably I would mainly do it with css3 transforms over a list, using jQuery only to rotate the reel.

Comment: You're very negative and obviously have little experience with adaptation in today's ever evolving world. This guy is asking a legitimate question from a client who has a legitimate request.  Making such a site doesn't have to be choppy and bad, though it may require i predisclosure for older browsers possibly being run on older systems with older OS's, but that doesn't mean it cant and shouldnt be done.  If we continue to baby-feed all the users out there who refuse to upgrade for various reasons, standards would never change and progress would never be made.

Comment: No It´s not what I need, I know what a carousel or a images slider is, but what I need is a non flat carousel, I want a carousel that act as cylinder. I would like to see the flat shaped container (A rectangle on the screen), and when It moves out of the screen I want to see it arched like following the trayectory of a cylinder (seen it from its center) and that the new information enters fron the other side of the screen in the same way but in the other direction! Do you know any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i know there are numerous solutions for your problem:

1. Use some carousel plugin, or write one because you need some advanced stuff (looping and ability to jump to certain "slide") and then enhance it with some CCS3 (look into [reveal.js concave example](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/?transition=concave))

   pro: graceful fallback for browser without css3d support
   contra: CSS3 + javascript
2. Place all the "slides" in 3D space and rotate the scene via CSS3D (eg, via :target selector or js)

   contra: no fallback at all, i dont want to know how this would look in ie7
3. Use Canvas and either WebGL or manual vertex transformation and texturing

   pro: no CSS3D, more supported (i think canvas is more supported, correct me if i am wrong)
   contra: no fallback, not indexable, lot to code, depends hard on js
4. Flash

   pro + contra discussed way too often

Offtopic: nice design idea, share results

Comment: Wow!!! This is a great answer!!! A lot of options, with their pros and contras, concise and accurate. I think i will go for the first option, that example looks really nice. On Chrome works awersome, on FF nice, and on IE... well...Maybe I can use other plugin in that case.
The other ideas are good too, except the last one (for this situation), because my client dont want Flash on his site. Ty!
I will post my results soon!

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [jQuery Reel](http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel)?

or for simple carousel plugins look [at this article](http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php?id=55)

just [something](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/3d/css/) else to check out, maybe useful in that it teaches more about the 3d uses of HTML5 and CSS3 which could be extremely useful to ya.  Another thought, at my work, we designed an online site editor based on html5, css3, and a little jQuery.js using the [`canvas`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) element, and it is 180° panoramic

Comment: why -1? it's the plugin he is looking for? if you're gonna -1 someone, at least explain why, please

Comment: I dont understand why anyone will  give -1 for this answer. At least,  a description should have been given for giving -1. Giving +1.

Comment: he can use the plugin suggested by SpYk3HH and change the css. It's easy. I did it in my early days as a PHP developer hehe

Comment: SpYk3HH, Jquery Reel is not what i need, that plugin is useful for create 3d picture views. 
And a simple carrousel plugin Is not what my client want. 
And besides a solution that involves CSS3 or HTML5 Is not convinient because there are few browsers that Support it
Do you have read my update? Maybe im not explaining the problem clearly! Im adding a video of the effect so you can watch it.

PS: i didnt give you -1...

Comment: My thought was, you can use the "aspects" of jQuery Reel and use a little tricky js and css to modify the images to be replaced with html content.  On another thought tho, you can still use the "canvas" element of html5 to create the entire thing in 3d, although it will take some serious work and effort to make it smooth. My suggestion: get Komodo Edit, and just test a couple things out using Codeigniter for PHP, jQuery, and various plugins, and maybe even look at some HTML5 CSS3 sights.  What you want to do can be done even for mobile, but will not be backwards compat for browsers =HTML4-

Comment: And as for the comment, in your comment, that I just noticed about lack of browser support. When doing somthing this large and interactive, it may be best to sit with your client and weigh the pros/cons of older browser support. On the pro side, a few more customers, but on the con side, it's going to take longer to develop and that could mean loss of possible income while the client waits on a solution supporting that small market area.